# Updating a table column based on another tables results using mysql only

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have a set of results - `SELECT id FROM recruit_index WHERE YEAR NOT LIKE '2011'`

I need to update another table column based on each of the above ids using mysql only.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance

Mike

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
UPDATE recruit_index, other_table set other_table.column={new value here}
WHERE recruit_index.id = other_table.id and recruit_index.year not like '2011';
```

Comment: +1: I like ANSI-92 JOIN syntax over the ANSI-89 used here, but otherwise 100% correct for MySQL